# Hotel Reception Probability Math Problem

Tags: probability

have to hand in a project about this tomorrow and thought this would be a cool addition to justify having only two staff members at a reception desk rather than three. We have calculated that

the time needed to check in one guest is 8 mins and 7 seconds
the time available for check in is three hours so 180 mins (they can walk in randomly at any time during the 3 hours and don't know each other
5 guests are coming on this particular day
what is the chance that two checkins intersect (occur at the same time)??

Thank you in advance for your help

Kind Regards,

Chase

Comment: exactly $2$ or $2$ or more?

Comment: Alex thanks for the quick response.sorry for not formulating that clearly What i mean is what is the chance that any check ins happen at the same time. so this would also include three 2, 3, 4 or all 5 walking up to the reception guest at the same time.

Comment: Can you not use Poisson process with $\lambda = \frac{5}{(180*60)}$ and T = 487 seconds and then use P(R = 2) = $\dfrac{e^{-\lambda *T}(\lambda T)^{2}}{2!}$ and find the probability = 0.020281

Comment: wow thats amazing! but seeing as i'm very new to probability would it be possible to explain the process bit by bit. I know its a lot to ask, thanks so much for your help til now satish

Comment: Perfect Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use Poisson process with $\lambda = \frac{5}{(180*60)}$ and T = 487 seconds and then use P(R = 2) = $\dfrac{e^{-\lambda *T}(\lambda T)^{2}}{2!}$ and find the probability = 0.020281

P(R = 3) = 0.001524029

P(R = 4) = 8.58913E-05

P(R = 5) = 3.87254E-06

Required Probability = 0.021895209

Just to make sure that the sum is = 1

P(R=0) = 0.798171095

P(R=1) =0.179933546

If you sum them all it will be equal to 1.

Hope this answers your question.

Edit:  $\lambda$ is the expected number of guests per unit time, T = time during which you want to measure the counts and the formula for the probability =

P(R = r, given $\lambda$, T) = $\dfrac{e^{-\lambda *T}(\lambda T)^{r}}{r!}$

Comment: How do i accept it? actually my first time using this site